# Prove $S ⊂ V$ is an affine subspace iff $λs_1 + (1 − λ)s_2 ∈ S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $S$ is a subset of $V$. I want to prove $S$ is an affine subspace iff $λs_1 + (1 − λ)s_2 \in S$ for all $s_1,s_2 \in S$.

I can show the forward direction by writing $s_1$ and $s_2$ as $v+w_1$ and $v+w_2$, and factor out the $v$, but I'm not sure how to do the other direction (i.e. how to prove $s \in S \Rightarrow s \in v + W$ for some $v \in V,W \subseteq V$).

Comment: Do you assume $S$ is nonempty?  Or does your definition of affine subspace allow for the empty set, maybe as a special case?

Comment: @DanielSchepler S is assumed to be nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can show that for every $s\in S$ the space $-s+S$ has the same property. But since the zero vector lies in $-s+S$ we know that $-s+S$ contains scalar multiples and therefore is also closed under addition (for $s',s'' \in -s+S$ consider $\lambda=2, s_1=\frac{1}{2}s'$ and $s_2=-s''$).